# NullPointerException but compiling?

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception

I'm writing a simple command line game.
I've got many functions and all, and will only post the essential here.

Problem: The program compiles but when `levelup()` is called and a number is chosen, I get this:

```
        You have 5 skill points to spend.
        What would you like to upgrade?
        [1:]    STR                     [2:]    DEF
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Game.levelup(cmdquest.java:300)
        at Game.start(cmdquest.java:336)
        at Menu.show_menu(cmdquest.java:195)
        at cmdquest.main(cmdquest.java:263)
```

Here is my code:

```
class Player{
    String name;
    int hp;
    int str;
    int def;
    String  eff;

    Player(String n) {
    name = n;
    hp = 100;
    str = 1;
    def = 1;
    eff = "none";
    }
}


class Game{

    static Player p;

    static void levelup(){
        while (points > 0){
            System.out.println("\t[1:]\tSTR\t\t\t[2:]\tDEF");
            int lvlup = kb.nextInt();

            switch (lvlup){
                case 1: p.str++;
                    break;
                case 2: p.def++;
                    break;
            }

            points--;
        }

    //variables
    static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int points = 5;

    }

static void start(){

        System.out.print("\t\t\t\tAnd so our adventure starts.....");

        System.out.print("\tWhat's your name: ");
        String nome = kb.next();
        Player p = new Player(nome);

        System.out.println("\tHello " + p.name);
        System.out.println("\tYou have 5 skill points to spend.\n\tWhat would you like to upgrade?");
        levelup();

    }



class cmdquest{

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Importing foes.txt to create objects of foes
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("foes.txt");
    Scanner imp = new Scanner(file);  

    for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
        foes[i]=foe.leDados(imp);
    }
    //____________________________________________

    Game.start();

}
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?
What am I doing wrong? I sense it's a class problem with the class "Player" and the object being created in the "Game" class.

Comment: probably didn't initialize `kb` or `p`

Comment: The stack trace tells you exactly where the error is.  Look at line 299 of `cmdquest.java`.

Comment: Can you please specify exactly which line is 299? Also, just to clarify - `NullPointerException` is a runtime exception. This means it will never be caught during compilation, only during run time.

Comment: I guess it's `p`, it's not initialized!

Comment: nullpointers are not checked at compile time although you can use verifiers such as ESC Java to try and detect these before execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get a `NullPointerException` because `p` is `null`.  What you've done here:

```
Player p = new Player(nome);
```

is declare a *local* variable `p`.  The static class variable `p` is untouched, so it remains `null`.

This is called [shadowing (JLS, Section 6.4.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1):

> Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another
>   declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be
>   used to refer to the declared entity.

...

> A declaration d of a type named n shadows the declarations of any
>   other types named n that are in scope at the point where d occurs
>   throughout the scope of d.

Remove `Player`, so the reference to the static class variable `p` is what you want:

```
p = new Player(nome);
```

Comment: It worked!
Thank you very much!
I am finally able to keep on working on this project.
Thank you!