# Null Pointer Exception for Java

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm currently getting started with the use of LWJGL for making java games and I'm in the middle of making a basic pong-like game. However I keep getting a NullPointerException on this line.

```
paddle.move(1)
```

the full command is:

```
private GOPlayer paddle;
public void getInput(){
    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W))
        paddle.move(1);
}
```

GOPlayer.move is:

```
    public static final float SPEED = 4f;
    public void move(float mag){
        this.y += SPEED * mag;
}
```

I did initalize paddle

```
objects = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
GOPlayer paddle = new GOPlayer(0, Display.getHeight()/2 - GOPlayer.SIZEY/2, null);
objects.add(paddle);
```

I just can't seem to figure it out, it's probably something really obvious as usual.

Comment: Did you initialize `paddle`?

Comment: `private GOPlayer paddle = new GOPlayer();` maybe? I can't see that you're initializing `paddle`.

Comment: yes I did initialize paddle

Comment: You aren't initializing paddle anywhere -- you need something like paddle = new GOPlayer(); in your code

Comment: insert a line like assert(paddle!=null); immediately before you call move() . Please also post the entire stack trace if paddle is initialized.

Comment: where would I put the assert

Comment: `GOPlayer paddle = new GOPlayer(...` should probably be `paddle = new GOPlayer(...`, or you'll just initialize your local variable.

Comment: Your problem is called *variable shadowing*. Please see [duplicate problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964869/nullpointerexception-but-compiling) for more on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all of your code, `paddle` can only be `null` as it hasn't been initialized.

Do something like `private GOPlayer paddle = new GOPlayer();` or similar, depending on how you create `GOPlayer` objects.

And in reaction to your initialization: instead of `GOPlayer paddle = new GOPlayer(0, Display.getHeight()/2 - GOPlayer.SIZEY/2, null);`, do `paddle = new GOPlayer(0, Display.getHeight()/2 - GOPlayer.SIZEY/2, null);` as you have already declared `paddle` as you seem to want to use the field (`private GOPlayer paddle`) but you create a new local variable instead...

Answer (score 2):

Ok I just needed to remove the first GOPlayer from

```
GOPlayer paddle = new GOPlayer(0, Display.getHeight()/2 - GOPlayer.SIZEY/2, null);
```

Thanks Joachim Isaksson